# LC Low Pass Filter Design

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter

I am attempting to design a low-pass filter for a subwoofer, as the audio amplifier that is connected to it does not filter any of the sound coming in, and it is getting pumped full of high frequency sound. I have settled on a Butterworth LC filter, and want a crossover frequency of around 200Hz. I have determined that I want a capacitor somewhere in the range of 140-160 uF and an inductor in the range of 4.5-6.5 mF to hit that frequency, and from a circuit standpoint, it seems to make sense. Source: [this](http://www.erseaudio.com/Second-Order-2-Way) website

Here is where I hit a difficulty. I am aware that I don't want an inductor with very much DC resistance and is rated for a high current throughput (possibly in excess of 5A). I don't know which to choose.

I also am at a loss for the capacitor to choose, as I need one which is two-way (able to handle AC), but I am not sure for the other requirements of it.
If anyone can clarify these points for me, and give suggestions as to the actual parts to use, I would be forever grateful. It is also worth noting that I am on somewhat of a budget, so please try to recommend affordable products, even if they have lower performance.

Comment: "a capacitor able to handle AC" well, that's what capacitors do.

Comment: I'll be honest, and from experience, I'd say this question would probably work far better on https://electronics.stackexchange.com than here, not only because it's kind of only borderline about signal processing, but also because the low-level analog hardware audio guys are active over there, more than here. (not saying that we don't have great audio signal engineers here, but LC filters ... feels more electronic-y than signal process-y)

Comment: Haha, I did post it there, and they sent me over here. As for the AC business, it is true that capacitors can handle varying signals, but some of them have a specific polarity that will wreck the capacitor if current is pushed through the wrong way. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/327664/polarized-electrolytic-capacitor-reverse-polarization

Comment: @ReedPetersen I've addressed the matter of polarization in [my answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/383050/95619), you probably missed it. Also about the inductor. And I don't see anywhere an answer or comment pointing you to dsp.ee, maybe I missed it?